# He was visiting Berlin and (was) seventeen

Tags: verbs, conjunctions

"He was seventeen and visiting Berlin, when he got hit by a car." This is a correct sentence, right? "He was visiting Berlin and seventeen, when he got hit by a car." So is this one alright too? It seems a bit weird to combine 'visiting' and 'seventeen'.

Thanks!

Comment: The reason it's odd is that is contains a garden path, i.e., an invitation to a wrong parse. You mean to have a compound predicate: *He was visiting Berlin and* [was] *seventeen*. But you suggest a compound predicate (as though *seventeen* was a second German city to visit).

Comment: The comma doesn't belong.  And one presumes that he was 17 for longer than his visit to Berlin, so "seventeen", being the broader qualification, comes first.

Comment: 'He was seventeen, and visiting Berlin ...' is idiomatic, even though 'was' is used in different ways here (copula and deleted auxiliary), but 'He was visiting Berlin, and seventeen ...' is totally non-idiomatic though equally grammatical and unambiguous. I'm guessing that the more general / fundamental descriptor is placed first. Compare 'He is 2 and quite a handful'.

Comment: I would suggest putting the primary point first, which will provide a context for the rest. *When he got hit by a car, he was seventeen and visiting Berlin.*

Comment: @RichF But note that you wouldn't usually reverse the last two points.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth With the clauses reversed, an argument can be made for primacy of either age or location.  I would probably rephrase on reversing them, though -- something like *... he was visiting Berlin at the age of 17."

Comment: "When he was seventeen, while visiting Berlin he got hit by a car."  "When he got hit by a car while visiting Berlin, he was seventeen". "When he was seventeen, he got hit by a car while visiting Berlin." "At the age of 17, when he was visiting Berlin, he got hit by a car." At the age of 17 when he got hit by a car, he was visiting Berlin".

Comment: @mahmud koya  Yes, but those are emphasising different things, and are not all the unmarked choice.

Comment: I can see the problem you point to. 'He was over six foot tall and visiting Berlin, when he got hit by a car' coordinates the almost uncoordinatable. One might just about be able to put it in a context where it wouldn't be ludicrous. But ''He was seventeen and visiting Berlin, when he got hit by a car' sounds acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

The construction

> He was seventeen and visiting Berlin...

introduces parallelism that can be read in only one way: as attaching to *was*:

> He was (1) seventeen and (2) visiting Berlin...

But when we reverse the order of (1) and (2), we introduce a new structural possibility with regard to where the parallel terms may attach. We still have this possibility:

> He was (1) visiting Berlin and (2) seventeen...

But now we also have this possibility:

> He was visiting (1) Berlin and (2) seventeen...

Almost instantaneously we recognize that "He was visiting seventeen" doesn't make sense, and therefore that *visiting* can't be the correct attachment point for the parallel terms. But some part of our brain has to check and reject that possibility before confirming the intended parallel structure. This very brief misdirection is what deadrat, in a comment above, terms a "garden path."

Perhaps to spare listeners and readers avoidable work, many speakers and writers favor the construction that has only one possible parallel structure. Certainly, "He was seventeen and visiting Berlin..." seems idiomatically more natural than "He was visiting Berlin and seventeen..."; but whether the idiomatic preferability of the easier-to-interpret construction in this case is owing more generally to its relative structural simplicity I can't confidently say.

Comment: Hmm, *he was seventeen and travelling* vs *he was travelling and seventeen* - only single words throughout, but the former phrase flows better.